# How to Access file name from the file path name in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

my question is I can get file name and execute my output logic correctly
But I need to get the filepathname from that I need to execute my output logic.

```
    JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox(flist[i].getName());
```

When I use this above  line my program works correctly

```
 JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox(flist[i].getPath());
```

I need to get the  file path too so i used this line but Im getting error!

Flist[i] it has files chosen from a directory that are stored in a array list.

Before I would access

```
String filename = tmp.getText();
```

my output logic works fine!

Now [i] it needs to get the file name from the file path also!
     JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox(flist[i].getPath());

Here the [i] works in below of  my snippet code:

```
    Iterator<JCheckBox> i = aL.iterator();
    boolean once=false;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
        JCheckBox tmp = i.next();
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        frame.invalidate();
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
        //scroll adder
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(panel);
        jScrollPane1.add(tmp);
        jScrollPane1.revalidate();

        if(tmp.isSelected()) {
            String filepathNName =  tf.getText() +"\\"+ tmp.getText();
            //filepathNName = System.getProperty("path.separator");
            String filename = tmp.getText();
            System.out.println("filename = " + filename);
            System.out.println("filepaname = " + filepathNName);
            System.out.println("outputDir = " + outputDir);
            boolean success = latestex1.exlCreator(filepathNName, outputDir, filename);

            if(success&&!once)
            { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Completed. Pls refer to the path " + outputDir + " for output files");once=true; 

            }
             else if (once!=true) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OOPS.You have to set the destination path!!!");once=true;
             }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox(flist[i].getName()); This one has abc.txt JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox(flist[i].getpath()); This one has c:/abc.txt but the outputdir will read only abc.txt that is it will read after c:/ So  String filename = new File(tmp.getText()).getName(); this method is also not applicable